# How to configure Spring jaxb2Marshaller globally?

Tags: spring, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I use smth like this in Spring config:

```
    @Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller(){
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.my.package");
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
    jaxb2Marshaller.setAdapters(new LangPropertyAdapter());
}
```

I want to make Spring use this marshaller and my adapters to deserializing on RestController level but that is no effect. How to achieve it without explicit autowiring and manual marshalling? I don't want to use annotation XmlJavaTypeAdapter under the class. I want to configure adapters globally